# www and not www site look different apache Vhost settings

Tags: php, apache

Hi i have an account on linode, i just install my rails app..

The problem is when i enter www.site.com is different than site.com

In the Virtual host my settings are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    PassengerEnabled on
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias wwww.site.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/site.com/mfp/public
    <Directory "/srv/www/site.com/mfp/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    RailsEnv development
   <Location /srv/www/site.com/mfp/php/>
     PassengerEnabled off
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: **Four** w in word-wide-web?

Comment: That is awesome. It is very hard to find out that. You have a rocking eyes. @Mike :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here

```
ServerAlias wwww.site.com
```

Change it to

```
ServerAlias www.site.com
```